# How to create timer in Java?

Tags: java

I newbie in this programming language and when I created timer, got errors. 
First I import:

```
import java.util.Timer;
```

Then created timer:

```
    public class Road extends JPanel implements ActionListener {


    Timer Timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule();
    Image img = new ImageIcon("res/Road.png").getImage();

    Player p = new Player();

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.drawImage(img, p.layer1, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(p.img, p.x, p.y, null);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        p.move();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

But in lane timer.schedule() I got error that this is a syntax error on token "schedule" or identifier expected after this token

Comment: You can't execute code in the body of a class. You'll need to do it in a method, in a constructor, or in an instance initializer block.

Comment: Use a `javax.swing.Timer` not `java.util.Timer`

Answer (score 5):

```
Timer Timer = new Timer();
```

`Timer` is *not* reserved, but should be changed to `timer` to match the Java Naming Conventions.

Your code is in the wrong place; put it inside a method.

Finally, don't use the `Util` timer, use the `Swing` timer. Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: No it's not reserved.

Comment: He imported Timer, that reserves it.

Comment: Still, namimg variable same as class is super-trolling.

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't allow you to write statements outside of constructor or methods. Move your line to cinstructor or any method you want.

```
  Timer timer= new Timer(); //declaration allows
   timer.schedule(); // not allowed.
```

Only declarations allows outside of methods and  constructor.

As a side note, there is static blocks which allows you to do the same, I don't think you need that.

I strongly believe you are going to write that in constructor as when Road is constructing you are scheduling timer.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Use `javax.swing.Timer` for Swing programs, not `java.util.Timer`!

Then

```
Timer timer = new Timer(duration, this);
timer.start();
```

Also, the call to `.start()` need to be from within the constructor or some method

```
Timer timer;

public Road(){
    timer = new Timer(1000, this);
    timer.start();
}
```

---

As a side note. Don't override `paint` override `paintComponent` and call `super.paintComponent(g);`

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.drawImage(img, p.layer1, 0, null);
    g2.drawImage(p.img, p.x, p.y, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Case sensitivity:

```
Timer Timer = new Timer();
      ^---- capital T
timer.schedule();
^---lower case T
```