# about populate a String[] in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I wrote a class and declare a String[5] in class; then i tried to assign value to this array in class body directly without a method. I got tons of errors. Then I tried to define a method to called later to populate this array. No error this time. I don't understand why i can't assign value in class body directly, like this: aString[0] = "today". New to java. I know I missed some important concepts. I tried to google and didn't find a answer. Please help me to explain it.

this doesn't work:

```
//: com/instar/Test1.java;
//defining String[];
package com.instar;
public class Test1{
    private static String[] bString = new String[5];
    bString[0] = "Today";
    bString[0] = "Today";
    bString[2] = " snowing";
    bString[3] = " and";
    bString[4] = "cold!";
    }
}
```

this works:

```
//: com/instar/Test1.java;
//defining String[];
package com.instar;
public class Test1{
    private static String[] aString = new String[5];
    private static String[] bString = new String[5];
    public void populateArray(){
        bString[0] = "Today";
        bString[0] = "Today";
        bString[2] = " snowing";
        bString[3] = " and";
        bString[4] = "cold!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code contains compilation errors

Comment: Share your full code.

Comment: Few minutes back ,someone asked this type of question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887721/how-to-create-timer-in-java  You are facing the same issue.Read my post once it possible :http://stackoverflow.com/a/20887754/1927832

Comment: You should be specific about what kind of "error" you are getting. Is it an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException? Is it a NullpointerException? Is it a code compilation error? If so, what kind?

Answer (score 6):

You may need static initializer.

This should work:

```
//: com/instar/Test1.java;
//defining String[];
package com.instar;
public class Test1{
    private static String[] bString = new String[5];
    static {
      bString[0] = "Today";
      bString[2] = " snowing";
      bString[3] = " and";
      bString[4] = "cold!";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, try this:

```
private static String[] bString = new String[]{"Today", " snowing", " and", "cold!"};
```

Comment: Note that there's no need for `new String[]` when initializing at the declaration site. It's clearer though that a new object is being created

Comment: thanks. it works. i am so stupid i forgot constructor and initializer block.

Comment: @TwistedMeadow that's not really accurate. This had nothing to do with a constructor, it was a syntax error. The problem was that you were trying to execute statements directly in a class body, which you cannot do in Java. What you forgot to do was put your static code inside a "static{ }" block. Don't mean to nitpick, but I wanted to make sure you really understand what the problem was :)

Comment: thanks man, i see what you mean. Executing an assignment statement directly is not allowed in a class body. I just get used to the python syntax

Comment: @TwistedMeadow If you are coming from Python and want to use a JVM language but don't HAVE to use Java, I would suggest using Scala. It's a bit more similar to Python than Java. Also, it doesn't require a "static" block in situations like this ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have statements like that outside of a method, constructor, or initializer block.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment isn't allowed outside of a method or a constructor by themselves, just like you can't call `System.out.println("")` outside of a method/constructor. (Not totally sure why, but I know you can't.)

But, there is a solution to your problem. I'm assuming you want the assignment of the variables to be done statically so that rules out putting the assignment in a constructor. You can do two things then:

First, (and probably the easiest), you can use what's called an *array constant*. These allow you to set the values of arrays while you're declaring them. (But **only** while you're declaring them.) That looks like this:

```
public static String[] bString = {"Today", "Today", " snowing", " and", "cold!"};
```

You don't need to specify the size of the array because it's inferred by how many elements you included in your array constant.

Secondly, you can declare a static method to do this for you, which allows you to use assignments, (Because they *are* allowed inside methods.) That would look like this:

```
public static String[] getMyStringArray() {
    static String[] bString = new String[5];
    bString[0] = "Today";
    bString[1] = "Today";
    bString[2] = " snowing";
    bString[3] = " and";
    bString[4] = "cold!";
    return bString;
}
```

I personally would use the first one, as it is easier and cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Ahh, you explained pretty well, I can't upvote as my daily vote limit exceeded.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Actually I don't think this is explained very well and in fact saying "Assignment isn't allowed outside of a method or a constructor" is incorrect. You can assign a value to a variable inside a class body. You just can't execute logic without wrapping that in a "static{}" block.

Comment: Also, it is incorrect to call `public static String[] bString = {"Today", "Today", " snowing", " and", "cold!"};` an "array constant" because it is not final, so it is NOT constant.

Comment: @torbinsky I was referring to `{"Today", "Today", " snowing", " and", "cold!"}` as my array constant. I called it that because when you attempt to use one outside of a declaration in eclipse, it posts an error saying "Cannot use array constant outside of declaration." Simply writing the above cannot be changed without your disk being corrupted or your code being modified, which you can do to modify anything marked `final`, too. So, essentially, the above phrase between `{` and `}` is a constant (_unchanging_) value.

Comment: @AndrewG Ah, I see. Thanks for correcting me on that. However, I still think this answer is a bit confusingly worded and misleading overall. Especially your last code example, which somewhat out of context shows how to declare static method and does not show OP how to actually use it. I would say declaring an entire method to initialize a variable in this way is not a good approach.

Comment: @torbinsky I have to agree with you that it isn't a good approach; I would never use something like that if I could avoid it. I merely added that to illustrate the possibility of one doing that. I also didn't demo how to use it because I was assuming that the OP would know how to call a method. I do, however, see your point. Thanks for the feedback. I'm always learning.

Comment: @AndrewG As am I, so thanks again for that correction earlier. I understand your assumption as it's easy to make when you are familiar with a language. I think, judging from OP's question, that even that may have been to much of a leap :) In any case, happy learning and thanks for engaging in constructive conversations!

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why i can't assign value in class body directly

You can in the declaration with the right syntax.

```
private static String[] bString = new String[] 
{
    "Today",
    "Today",
    " snowing",
    " and",
    "cold!"
}
```

allows you to assign values to the array on declaration. However generally, you should do these kinds of things in a constructor. Perhaps you should read the java tutorials a little bit.