# Assignment in anonymous inner class Java

Tags: java

Here I have a class that contains an anonymous inner class:

```
public class Example {
    int value;
    Example(int value) {
        this.value = value;     
    }

    void bumpUp() {
        value++;
    }
    static Example makeExample(int startVal) {
        return new Counter(startVal) {

            int bumpValue = 2;
//          value = startVal;

            void bumpUp() {                 
                bumpValue = (bumpValue == 2) ? 1: 2;
                value+= bumpValue;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the line that says `value = startVal`, Eclipse throws an error saying the above line is an error. Why can't I put `value = startVal` there?

Thanks!

Comment: The same reason you can't put it in a non-anonymous class. It's in the body of the class and you can't have statements directly in the body of a class. There's some duplicate of that somewhere here...

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889310/about-populate-a-string-in-java), but it has to be clear that what comes after the `{` in an anonymous class declaration is the body of that class.

Comment: Actually the error that I'm seeing: `non-static field "value" cannot be referenced from a static context` > @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: `static Example makeExample(int startVal)` means that your method should return `Example`, not `Counter` (unless `Counter` extends/implements somehow `Example` which you didn't mention in your question).

Comment: You can access only `final` members of method or class in an anonymous inner class. Again if make those variables final, you cannot re-assign in your inner-class. I suggest you pass them to Constructor of inner class :)

Comment: I believe you wanted this to be `new Example(startVal)` rather than `new Counter(startVal)`. In this case, that statement is not actually needed, because `startVal` is going to be passed to `Example`'s constructor which assignes it to `this.value` already.

Comment: @RealSkeptic.. If OP's code is compiling fine without that line, he must have made `Counter extends Example` :) but like you said he should create `new Example` which makes sense to makeExample method as well

Comment: @Arkantos my own suspicion is that in his own IDE it's `Counter` and he changed it for posting on StackOverflow, but forgot to change all occurrences. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Hmmm.. that's a possibility, need to wait for OP to confirm on that :)

Comment: @Magnamag Yes, the logic of that overriding method is indeed questionable.

Comment: @RealSkeptic is right; I meant to change it to Example for SO. My apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, putting that line there is a syntax error, because you cannot have instructions outside of a method. And you're attempting to put an instruction within the body of the anonymous inner class.

But above all, you don't need that line, neither in a constructor (which is impossible for an anonymous inner class), nor in an initializer block.

**The constructor of the superclass is automatically invoked when constructing the anonymous inner class instance**, and `startVal` is passed along to the constructor of `Example`, where it's finally assigned to the attribute `value`.

Finally, `new Counter(startVal)` doesn't make any sense (where's the `Counter` class)? I believe it's either a copy-paste error, or that you have the `Counter` class declared somewhere else. In this latter case, `Counter` should extend `Example`, or you'd get a compilation error.

Here's the code with all the fixes:

```
public class Example {

    int value;

    Example(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    void bumpUp() {
        this.value++;
    }

    static Example makeExample(int startVal) {
        return new Example(startVal) {

            int bumpValue = 2;

            @Override
            void bumpUp() {
                this.bumpValue = (this.bumpValue == 2) ? 1 : 2;
                this.value += this.bumpValue;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example a = Example.makeExample(7);
        System.out.println(a.value);
        a.bumpUp();
        System.out.println(a.value);
        a.bumpUp();
        System.out.println(a.value);
        a.bumpUp();
        System.out.println(a.value);
        a.bumpUp();
        System.out.println(a.value);
        a.bumpUp();
        System.out.println(a.value);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
7
8
10
11
13
14
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems here:

you are using a statement in your class body

```
value = startVal;
```

even if it's fixed you will still refer to a non-static field from a static method

```
static Example makeExample(int startVal)
```